# Number of suggested edits indicator showing wrong number

Tags: support, review

Over the past day I've noticed that the orange indicator on the top bar, which shows the number of suggested edits awaiting review, isn't working correctly.

The number indicated does not agree with the number shown on the review page, and the number on the top bar seems to change more or less at random.

This is only happening on the ELL site, not on any others where I can review suggested edits.
It is happening on more than one PC and on different browsers.

Do we have a bug on ELL, or is something more mysterious happening at my end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's wrong on purpose.

It's a SE-wide design decision to show approximate total pending review tasks across the site, not the subset of tasks that are available to you, because they decided it was too expensive to calculate the latter in the header.  It just happens *at the moment* that it lines up for you on other SE sites.  A week from now, it might be some other SE site where they happen not to line up.

It used to be a suggested edit indicator and was, as far as I'm aware, accurate.  That was much nicer, but they broke it on purpose.

I just ignore the brown number now.

Comment: Ahh… was just about to post a meta question on this… though I've skipped a few [being really way too new to be casting important votes on ELL] they still show in the orange/brown flag. I really wish they wouldn't. maybe I'll get used to it but right now it's a constant irritant; I like my screen clean ;)